# Synthetic functions in python

Tags: python, function, python-internals

In python I can create a class without class statement:

```
MyClass = type('X', (object,), dict(a=1))
```

Is there a way to create a function without 'def'?
Thats as far as i got...

```
d={} # func from string
exec'''\
def synthetics(s):
    return s*s+1
''' in d

>>> d.keys()
['__builtins__', 'synthetics']
>>> d['synthetics']
<function synthetics at 0x00D09E70>
>>> foo = d['synthetics']
>>> foo(1)
2
```

Comment: @ eumiro -- :) i was expecting more of a workaround, but good bet.

Comment: But in lambdas, you can't have assignment or `print` statements, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, yes, this is possible. The type of a function is, like all other types, a constructor for instances of that type:

```
FunctionType = type(lambda: 0)
help(FunctionType)
```

As you can see from the help, you need at minimum code and globals. The former is a compiled bytecode object; the latter is a dictionary.

To make the code object, you can use the code type's constructor:

```
CodeType = type((lambda: 0).func_code)
help(CodeType)
```

The help says this is "not for the faint of heart" and that's true. You need to pass bytecode and a bunch of other stuff to this constructor. So the easiest way to get a code object is from another function, or using the `compile()` function. But it *is* technically possible to generate code objects completely synthetically if you understand Python bytecode well enough. (I have done this, on a very limited basis, to construct signature-preserving wrapper functions for use in decorators.)

PS -- `FunctionType` and `CodeType` are also available via the `types` module.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a more direct way than the following, but here's a full-blown function without `def`. First, use a trivial `lambda` expression to get a function object:

```
>>> func = lambda: None
```

Then, `compile` some source code to get a code object and use that to replace the `lambda`'s code:

```
>>> func.__code__ = compile("print('Hello, world!')", "<no file>", "exec")
>>> func()
Hello, world!
```

Comment: There is a function type too: `func = types.FunctionType(compile( ... ), globals())`